# How to navigate with anchor in UIWebView (swift)

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I load a local html file in a UIWebview, and I have internal links (anchors) in the html contents :

```
<a href="#content1">..
<a href="#content2">
```

and then

```
<div id="content1">
```

But when I click on them, nothing happens.
How can I make anchors work ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are obliged to use UIWebView but you're probably aware that Apple now seems to require you use WKWebView in modern versions of iOS/OSX. With this in mind, if you were to use WKWebView instead you could handle this type of event with the webView( decidePolicyFor:, decisionHandler: ) delegate method. See the reference at https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate

Comment: Ok thanks, I will migrate to Xcode 8 and have a look

Comment: You won't need to migrate to XCode 8 if you don't want to ( although it's probably a good idea anyway); WebKit has been around for a while. Good luck!